# Unable to run matcher method in JSP page

Tags: java, regex, jsp

I was working on a project when I came across this weird error

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*,java.util.regex.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>

<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>SignUp Page</h1>
        <form action="NewFile.jsp" method="post">
         <br/>Email address<input type="text" name="email">
         <br/><input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
        <%
                      Pattern pattern;
                  Matcher matcher;

    final String email=request.getParameter("email");
        Pattern pt=Pattern.compile("^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$"); 
        Matcher mt=pt.matcher(email); 
        boolean bl=mt.find(); 

     if(!bl)
     {
         response.sendRedirect("SignUpError.jsp");
     }
     %>
     </html>
```

The issue is I am getting an error at the line

> Matcher mt=pt.matcher(email);

[image]

Comment: But it's supposed to work in jsp right? I specifically searched for regex that works for JSP, but it isn't working..

Comment: is `email` non-null ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi I'm not even taken to the page to input the email address, getting an error before I visit the page

Comment: are you passing request parameter `email` with the request to that page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug `request.getParameter("email")` its null.

Here is how to produce your error:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(".").matcher(null);
```

Exception you'll get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1140)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:291)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:211)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:888)
Java Result: 1
```

To overcome this error, do this:

```
if(email != null){
    Matcher mt=pt.matcher(email); 
    boolean bl=mt.find(); 
    ... other stuffs

}
```